# Creating a new attribute in an XML node using E4X in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for answering.

I did found your explanations and link suggestions interesting and encouraging.

Anyway, I did not make myself clear with my question. What I did want to know was how to create *any* property, even without knowing it's name. I did read several docs and tutorials until I figured it out. Hope this can be of help.

```
var data:XML = <node/>;
var $my_attr:String = 'id';
data.@[$my_attr] = 'foo';
```

Comment: Ah, now that's a different issue. I beleive data['@' + attrName] should also do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

To add attribute you need to write as

> xmlNode.attributes.@attr = "value";

Hope it works.

Thx
Amitd

Comment: Correction should be (remove @ from above) 

xmlNode.attributes.attr = "value";

Answer (score 1):

xmlNode.attributes['attribute'] = 'attribute value';

Answer (score 0):

Long answer: Please do read the documentation. It is indeed very rich. Entire chapters have been devoted to XML and E4X. [Here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_03.html)'s a link that may be helpful to you.

Short answer: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

dirkgently didn't directly tell you how to do it, I guess with an educational purpose.  Nonetheless, here's how:

```
var xml:XML = <node/>;
xml.@attr = "value";
```

Tada!  But please, RTFM.

Comment: @ turboHz I agree with David, It's really not good practice, for your own skills I mean, to not give it a shot yourself first and do at least a basic search in the documentation or on google.